# Find a line in a log and split the text batch

Tags: batch-file, logging, text-files

I am trying to make a simple batch file that will first look for a specified line of text in a log, then separate it, then average it. I know how to average it but the finding and then separating it are what I need to know how to do. This is a mockup of the log

```
[20:36:33] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT] Some text here that I don't need
[20:36:33] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT] Some more text here that I don't need
[20:36:33] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT] Text I want $30023
[20:36:33] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT] More text here that I don't need
[20:36:33] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT] Text I want $40324
```

I will go on like that for a while, I what to first find the text that will say something like Text I want $ and then a number. I want to then take that number and average it with the other numbers that It said previously. The message in the log Text I want a number will appear at maximum 30 seconds apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setlocal
set x=0
set n=0
for /f "delims=$ tokens=2" %%# in ('findstr /r /c:"Text I want \$[0-9]*$" "log.txt"') do (echo %%#
set /a x+=%%#
set /a n+=1)
set /a x=(2*x+n)/(2*n)
echo Average: %x%
```

This will find "Text I want $NUBMER" in log.txt and print out the number after the "$".

**EDIT:** I have discovered a limitation to this - If the last line in log.txt does not have a linebreak, i.e. if the last line of the .txt isn't empty, the last line will be ignored. Piping the output of `type` into `findstr` counters this:

```
for /f "delims=$ tokens=2" %%# in ('type "log.txt"^|findstr /r /c:"Text I want \$[0-9]*$"') do ...
```

Comment: With this find all the Text I want $NUMBER or just the first one?

Comment: @AnthonyJack It will print every number that matches the pattern.

Comment: I can only get the first one Text I want $NUMBER to display is this how is supposed to work?

Comment: @AnthonyJack Is the last line of the .txt empty? If not, see my edit.

Comment: Ok sorry but how would I then average these? In stead of echoing them could I some how average all the answers. Sorry I am really bad a the for command.

Comment: @AnthonyJack Left it out because you mentioned you already had something to average it. Does it need to be accurate? Normally batch can't work with decimals.

Comment: No it doesn't need to be extremely accurate, not in the decimals anyways, as for the averaging I was going to have a starting number a loop running the command to find it and put it into a variable then average that against the average, then set the new avgerage

Comment: @AnthonyJack Numbers will be floored. Also only works if they don't get too big during the addition (limit 2147483647).

Comment: When the last line is not terminated with a line-break, the `$` anchor of `findstr` does not work as it relies on the line-feed character (this behaviour I consider as a design flaw). When the last line *is* terminated with a line-break, there is still no empty line at the end (you'd need another line-break)...

Comment: To increase the accuracy a bit, you could change the line `set /a x/=n` to this: `set /a x=(2*x+n)/(2*n)`; this establishes proper rounding (round to nearest integer); the original approach always rounds downwards...

Comment: Thanks I'll try this